# Linux iptables DNAT 53306 to 127.0.0.1 3306

Tags: iptables, mysql, nat

mysql real port is `3306`。

I want public network using `53306` to visit mysql, and `3306` is not allowed access from public network.

How to write the iptables rules `DNAT 53306 to 127.0.0.1 3306`?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d <public IP> --dport 53306 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3306
```

What this rule does is:

- `-t nat` indicate the nat table
- `-A PREROUTING` meaning append this rule to bottom of `PREROUTING` chain
- `-p tcp` specific this rule only apply for tcp protocol
- `-d <public IP> --dport 53306` meaning match all traffic to `public ip` and to port `53306`.
- `-j DNAT` meaning jump to `DNAT` target
- `--to-destination 127.0.0.1:3306` specify your local ip and port

Comment: Instead of public IP `0.0.0.0` is also an option, albeit less specific.

Comment: @gnouc does that actually work?  Can you DNAT to an IP that's on the same machine?

Comment: @Creek: It's alone may not work, since when packet to localhost simply drop by `iptables`. I think we need enable `route_localnet`.

Comment: @Gnouc Maybe.  I was thinking that the packet would traverse the `INPUT` chain instead of `FORWARD` and never reach `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @Creek You are right, IN IP Secrity Protocol,packet never reach loopback address.

Comment: @ikool then you should perform the port forward on the gateway (router)

Comment: @ikool if you use a second device then you'll have to move the `mysql` socket to a physical interface instead of `127.0.0.1`